# AttributeError: 'AstypeContext' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: types, computer-vision, pytorch, h5py

```
sal_maps_hf.shape
(11, 32, 32, 3)
```

I want to change the dtype of sal_maps_hf to nint8 so

```
sal_maps_hf.dtype
dtype('<f4')

sal_maps_hf = sal_maps_hf.astype(np.uint8)
print(sal_maps_hf.dtype)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 print(sal_maps_hf.dtype)
>
> AttributeError: 'AstypeContext' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: Assuming `sal_maps_hf` is a h5py dataset, here's how to apply @hpualj's answer to your example: `with sal_maps_hf.astype(np.uint8); out=sal_maps_hf[:]`. Then when you check `out.dtype`, you should get `dtype('uint8')`. Note that `out` is an np.ndarray read from `sal_maps_hf` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for a `h5py.dataset` `astype` method:

```
astype(dtype)
Return a context manager allowing you to read data as a particular type. Conversion is handled by HDF5 directly, on the fly:

>>> dset = f.create_dataset("bigint", (1000,), dtype='int64')
>>> with dset.astype('int16'):
...     out = dset[:]
>>> out.dtype
dtype('int16')
```

Note, this does not show the `dtype` of the `astype` directly.  An `astype` applied to a numpy array does produce a new array.  But with `h5py` doesn't work quite like that.